# SSL WordPress on Windows

Tags: wordpress, windows, apache, ssl

I have an old WordPress application on a Apache2.2 web server on an Windows server. It is working but I want it to work with SSL. Unfortunately, the admin username and password are missing so I have to set it in config files.

What I did:

- I enabled *LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so* and *Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf* lines in Apache httpd.conf file.
- I added these lines in the httpd-vhosts.conf file:

> ```
> <IfModule headers_module>
>     RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
>     RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-SSL expr=%{HTTPS}
> </IfModule>
> ```

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName example.com
>     Redirect / https://example.com/
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:443>
> ServerName example.com
> DocumentRoot "C:\AppServ\www\example"
>   <Directory "C:\AppServ\www\example">
>       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>       AllowOverride All
>       Require all granted
>   </Directory>
>
>   SSLEngine on
>   SSLCertificateFile      "C:\AppServ\Apache2.2\conf\example.crt"
>   SSLCertificateKeyFile   "C:\AppServ\Apache2.2\conf\example.key"
>
>   ErrorLog logs\example-error_log
>   TransferLog logs\example-access_log 
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

The redirection doesn't work with this error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS